# cgi.FieldStorage() and .has_key() in Python3

Tags: python, forms, python-3.x, cgi

I have a html file with  and a separate python file.
I am looking for a formdata value with a specific id. My form in the html file is correct and works in Python 2.
In Python 2 the code is as follow, what can be the code in Python3 because I get the else error catch "op not found"

```
Import cgi
formdata = cgi.FieldStorage()

def main():

  if formdata.has_key("op"):
    op = formdata['op'].value
  else:
    print "op not found"
    show()
    sys.exit(1)
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The else block shouldn't be executed at all, in [Python 3 `has_key` has been removed](http://docs.python.org/3.1/whatsnew/3.0.html#builtins). Use `in` instead.